# VSCode How to Collapse/Expand in Source Control Tree View Panel

Tags: visual-studio-code

No code, just want some extensions in regards of easy collapse all items in VSCode Tree View Panel.

Do you have any idea how to do that? VSCode extension?

Answer (score 2):

You can collapse all items in source control tree with :

`ctrl` + `a` + `left arrow`

Comment: And how do you expand it?